# wordpress widgets screen disappeared

Tags: widgets

Im having a weird problem. The screen where you manage widgets (drag and drop them from left to right) suddenly disappeared.

How can I access it?

It should be accessible via admin>themes>widgets but I dont have that option in the sub menu. Only have "themes" "menus" "editor"

Btw, Im using ithemes theme builder plugin.

Since I have access to the editor and can edit php I assume I have admin rights.

Comment: Deactivate all plugins, switch back to Twenty Ten.

Comment: thx its here again. but why doesnt it show when using ithemes child theme :S

Comment: I can access it via link but not in menu.

Comment: There is a WordPress core-related reason why you're observing `Appearance -> Widgets` disappearing (see answer below). But in general, if your issue is specific to a commercial Theme, you should consult the support offerings of that commercial Theme's developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is both a change in WordPress core in 3.5, and a problem specific to your commercial Theme.

In WordPress 3.5, [if a Theme does not register support for dynamic sidebars (i.e. Widgets), then the WP-Admin does not display the `Appearance -> Widgets` admin page](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21761). So, if the behavior changed between WordPress 3.4 and 3.5, or if the screen re-appears if you switch to Twenty Twelve/Eleven/Ten, then the problem is that your chosen Theme doesn't support Widgets.

Specific to your commercial Theme, iThemes builder, [this is a known bug](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/widgets-sub-menu-from-appearance-menu-is-missing?replies=7), and one that was [apparently fixed](http://ithemes.com/codex/page/Builder/Release_Notes/4.0.7). If you need any additional assistance with this commercial Theme, you should [contact the developer, iThemes](http://ithemes.com/forum/).